# How to reorder rows by a condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and one of their orders is correct for me. I want to make the other's order the same as the correct one. Here is the point, it's not about index numbers, order depends on a variable. Like this

df1

```
A   B
13  2
20  5
15  3
.   .
.   .
```

df2

```
A   B
15  3
13  2
20  5
.   .
.   .
```

I want the order of df2 to be same as df1, I put them in a for loop but it took long time (my real data is much greater than reproducible example)

Is there any easier way to make my wish real ? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think is to replace the index of `df2` by column `A` and then call it with loc:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [13,20,15], "B": [2,5,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [15,13,20], "B": [3,2,5]})
df2 = df2.set_index("A")
print(df2.loc[df1["A"]])
```

output is:

```
    B
A    
13  2
20  5
15  3
```

Is this ok for you?